# Sum with integer coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose the series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n
$$
converges for $\left\vert x\right\vert>1$ and $a_n\in\mathbb Z$. Is it true that $a_n=0$ for large enough $n$? I think this should be true, but can't seem to prove it.

Comment: Immediate from the [Cauchy-Hadamard theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem), or you can argue about partial sums.

Comment: First show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true. If the series converges for a certain $x$ satisfying $|x|>1$, you must have $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n x^n=0$. Since $x^n$ does not converge to zero, you must have $\lim a_n = 0$. If the terms of $a_n$ are integers, this can only happen if $a_n = 0$ for $n > n_0$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The fact that the series converges for a $x$ such that $|x|>1$ implies that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow 0} a_n x^n = 0, \quad \quad  \text{so} \quad \quad a_n = o \left( x^{-n}\right), \quad \quad  \text{so} \quad \quad \lim_{n \rightarrow 0} a_n  = 0$$

Now you can conclude.